# How to Implement Primary Key in Core Data for Iphone

Tags: iphone, core-data, primary-key

I am working on with Core Data. I need to keep a unique value of bandID within Core Data. 
In my data model i am having

```
bandImagePath
bandID ---------------primary Key
bandName
```

Code:

```
-(IBAction)addToFavButtonPressed:(id)sender
{   
    NSLog(@"add to fav button clicked");    
    SongRequestAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]; 
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];   
    NSManagedObject *addToFav;  
    addToFav = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"AddToFav" inManagedObjectContext:context];    
    [addToFav setValue:self.imageUrl forKey:@"bandImagePath"];
    NSLog(@"band image path url is %@",self.imageUrl);
    [addToFav setValue:self.bandName forKey:@"bandName"];
    NSLog(@"band name is %@",self.bandName);
    [addToFav setValue:self.bandId forKey:@"bandId"];
    NSLog(@"band ID is %@",self.bandId);
    //NSLog(@"eno is %@",eno.text);

    NSError *error;
    if (![context save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Whoops, couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }       
}
```

Comment: It is a mistake to approach Core Data design from an SQL viewpoint. Core Data is not SQL. Entities are not tables. Objects are not rows. Columns are not attributes. Core Data is an object graph management system that may or may not persist the object graph and may or may not use SQL far behind the scenes to do so. Trying to think of Core Data in SQL terms will cause you to completely misunderstand Core Data and result in much grief and wasted time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: you can't, automatically.

Long answer: Core Data does not provide a way to specify an attribute as "unique".  There are several reasons why.  Rest assured that if this were an easy thing to put in, it would have been put in long ago.  So how do you work around it?  Basically, you have to first [check to see if an `AddToFav` exists](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSFetchRequest_Class/NSFetchRequest.html) with the specified `bandId`.  If it does, then you don't create a new one.  If it doesn't, then you can.

Comment: Dave thanks for u r response.i will try to work on that implementation.

Comment: it is so easy to make an attribute unique key in Entity Framework. Why is it so hard in CoreData ? "If this were an easy thing to put in, it would have been put" is kinda lame answer.